# PHP and MySQL error when inserting user entered values into table

Tags: php, mysql

everything functions on the side of data validation and error gathering and such, I get a problem specifically where $r is being executed. I always get the echo error. I've used this same bit of code before, but for some reason isn't working. Just need a second look of eyes at it perhaps.

```
if (empty($errors)){
    $q = "INSERT INTO testTable (test1, test2) VALUES ('Test', 'Test')";
    $r = @mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

    if($r){
        echo 'Complete!';
    }
    else{ 
        echo 'error';
        }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

    include('footer.html');
    exit();
```

I can enter the statement manually in MySQL and it will add it to the table, so I don't think its a syntax error there, I am just a little tired at this point.

Comment: try with mysqli_error($dbc) in else part.

Comment: Change `echo 'error'` to `echo mysqli_error($dbc);` so you see the reason for the error.

Comment: Get the *real* error `or die(mysqli_error($dbc))` to `mysqli_query()` and remove the `@`

Comment: Yeah, it seems strange to ask a question about an error you're getting when *you've told it to not report any errors in your function call*.

Comment: I have changed it and now I just get a blank page. No indication of anything.

Comment: You probably made a syntax error when you changed it. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: [Blank page=White screen of death.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: I literally just copied and pasted it. my echo statement reads exactly as: else{ echo mysqli_error($dbc);}

Comment: Err... reads as what, **as code** instead of executing? If so, make sure you're using `.php` extension. How are you accessing this, local machine, hosted? as `file:///file.php`?

Comment: This is what we meant by checking for errors, on the PHP side of things and as per my link up there already. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything. Plus, your conditional statement `if (empty($errors)){` relies on it.

Comment: No it's a file hosted on a public server, and the MySQL is hosted on a separate one, the whole $dbc is the connection. I've never had a problem with that aspect before though.

Comment: Seeing that you may be new to MySQL. You're not mixing MySQL APIs with your code are you? We don't know what API you're using to connect with. Plus, a lot of missing code and I don't know if you read my comment just above concerning error reporting codes to add to your file(s).

Comment: Ok well I'm not going to stay around for any much longer. You have enough info to go on to find what's wrong with your code. I'm moving on; good luck.

Comment: I'm getting a lot of warnings saying that parameter 1 of mysqli_xxx must be mysqli. So does that mean that my $dbc variable isn't working properly?

Comment: Consult the answer I have given you below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I'm getting a lot of warnings saying that parameter 1 of mysqli_xxx must be mysqli. So does that mean that my $dbc variable isn't working properly?"*

The reason for that may very well be because your DB connection method is probably based on [`mysql_connect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) or PDO to connect with.

- Something you haven't posted in your question.

Those different MySQL APIs do **not** intermix with each other.

`mysql_` + `mysqli_` or PDO = **no love**. `mysqli_` + PDO, *same thing.*

Refer to both manuals:

- MySQLi: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- PDO: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

and use only "one" MySQL API, from beginning to end and **not** a "mix of".

---

You should also remove the `@` symbol(s) from your code. Those are error **suppressors** and won't help you when debugging code.

---

So your connection for `MySQLi_` would look something like this:

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") 
        or die("Error " . mysqli_error($dbc));
```

Unlike `mysql_`:

```
$dbc = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$dbc) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: My $dbc looks exactly like your mysqli_connect example. But I looked back up higher and saw that my mysqli_select_db() had the parameters in the wrong order. I had no idea that mysqli and mysql were different. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Burninrock24 Ah, glad to know this one was solved, *cheers* and you're welcome.

Comment: @Burninrock24 You can use all 4 parameters in `mysqli_connect()` rather than using `mysqli_select_db()`. Saves you a bit of code too.

Comment: Thanks again, what happened is that I was mixing and matching elements from different scripts that I had completed independent of each other, not knowing that there were compatibility issues between them. Thank you again!

Comment: @Burninrock24 It happens and you're welcome. The old `mysql_` method of connecting, required the connection variable being last, as opposed to `mysqli_` being the first.